# JavaFX ListView very slow

Tags: java, listview, javafx

I'm making a chat application using JavaFX for the GUI. I display the chat content in a ListView, but I have one big problem - it's very very slow. When I add new items to the list and especially when I scroll the list up/down. I think maybe it has something to do with the fact that the list refreshes itsellf every time a new item is added (each cell in the list!) and also refreshes every time I scroll up/down.
Does someone know what can I do to solve this problem? TNX

I override ListCell's updateItem:

```
chatListView.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<UserInfo>, ListCell<UserInfo>>() {
            @Override
            public ListCell<UserInfo> call(ListView<UserInfo> p) {
                ListCell<UserInfo> cell = new ListCell<UserInfo>() {
                    @Override
                    protected void updateItem(UserInfo item, boolean bln) {
                        super.updateItem(item, bln);

                        if (item != null) {
                            BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
                            ImageView profileImage = new ImageView(new Image(item.getImageURL()));
                            profileImage.setFitHeight(32);
                            profileImage.setFitWidth(32);

                            Rectangle clip = new Rectangle(
                                    profileImage.getFitWidth(), profileImage.getFitHeight()
                            );
                            clip.setArcWidth(30);
                            clip.setArcHeight(30);
                            profileImage.setClip(clip);
                            SnapshotParameters parameters = new SnapshotParameters();
                            parameters.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                            WritableImage image = profileImage.snapshot(parameters, null);
                            profileImage.setClip(null);
                            profileImage.setImage(image);

                            ImageView arrowImage = new ImageView(new Image("arrow1.png"));
                            ImageView arrowImage2 = new ImageView(new Image("arrow1.png"));
                            Label nameLabel = new Label(item.getUserName());
                            nameLabel.setStyle(" -fx-text-alignment: center; -fx-padding: 2;");

                            HBox hbox = null;
                            Label textLabel = new Label();
                            String messageText = splitTolines(item.getMessage());
                            textLabel.setText(messageText);
                            textLabel.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #a1f2cd; "
                                    + "-fx-padding: 10;\n"
                                    + "-fx-spacing: 5;");
                            hbox = new HBox(arrowImage, textLabel);

                            VBox vbox = new VBox(profileImage, nameLabel);
                            BorderPane.setMargin(vbox, new Insets(0, 10, 10, 10));
                            BorderPane.setMargin(hbox, new Insets(10, 0, 0, 0));

                            //Time
                            Date dNow = new Date();
                            SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
                            Label timeLabel = new Label(ft.format(dNow));
                            timeLabel.setStyle("-fx-font: 8px Tahoma;  -fx-width: 100%");

                            HBox hbox2 = new HBox(arrowImage2, timeLabel);
                            arrowImage2.setVisible(false);
                            VBox vbox2 = new VBox(hbox, hbox2);

                            borderPane.setCenter(vbox2);
                            borderPane.setLeft(vbox);
                            setGraphic(borderPane);
                        }
                    }
                };

                return cell;
            }
        });
```

Comment: You should include an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), otherwise your question is effectively unanswerable.

Comment: Yes, please provide sample code. Do you override ListCell's `updateItem` method? Do you do anything expensive in there? [Flowless](https://github.com/TomasMikula/Flowless) may or may not help in your situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. **Never ever** add (big) GUI Elements in `updateItem()` without checking if it is not already there.

   1. `updateItem()` is called everytime for **EVERY SINGLE ROW** when you scroll, resize or change gui in any other way.
   2. You should alway **reset the graphic to null** if you do not have an item or the second boolean of `updateItem(item, empty)` is false, because the second boolean is the **EMPTY** flag.
2. I recommend to you that you use a `VBox` instead of a `ListView`.

Comment: I took your advice and changed it to VBox - works great! thanks!

Comment: VBox is perfect! I'm too obsessed with ListView and ListCell.

Answer (score 1):

I just noticed that too. It's too slow even for a list containing only 5-10 items (with scaled images and text). Since I need no selection feature, I also rewrote the code to use VBox instead and the slowness is immediately gone!

To emulate the setItems, I have a helper function which you may find handy:

```
public static <S, T> void mapByValue(
        ObservableList<S> sourceList,
        ObservableList<T> targetList,
        Function<S, T> mapper)
{
    Objects.requireNonNull(sourceList);
    Objects.requireNonNull(targetList);
    Objects.requireNonNull(mapper);
    targetList.clear();
    Map<S, T> sourceToTargetMap = new HashMap<>();
    // Populate targetList by sourceList and mapper
    for (S s : sourceList)
    {
        T t = mapper.apply(s);
        targetList.add(t);
        sourceToTargetMap.put(s, t);
    }
    // Listen to changes in sourceList and update targetList accordingly
    ListChangeListener<S> sourceListener = new ListChangeListener<S>()
        {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(ListChangeListener.Change<? extends S> c)
            {
                while (c.next())
                {
                    if (c.wasPermutated())
                    {
                        for (int i = c.getFrom(); i < c.getTo(); i++)
                        {
                            int j = c.getPermutation(i);
                            S s = sourceList.get(j);
                            T t = sourceToTargetMap.get2(s);
                            targetList.set(i, t);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        for (S s : c.getRemoved())
                        {
                            T t = sourceToTargetMap.get2(s);
                            targetList.remove2(t);
                            sourceToTargetMap.remove2(s);
                        }
                        int i = c.getFrom();
                        for (S s : c.getAddedSubList())
                        {
                            T t = mapper.apply(s);
                            targetList.add(i, t);
                            sourceToTargetMap.put(s, t);
                            i += 1;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };
    sourceList.addListener(new WeakListChangeListener<>(sourceListener));
    // Store the listener in targetList to prevent GC
    // The listener should be active as long as targetList exists
    targetList.addListener((InvalidationListener) iv ->
        {
            Object[] refs = { sourceListener, };
            Objects.requireNonNull(refs);
        });
}
```

It can then be used like:

```
ObservableList<Bookmark> bookmarkList;
VBox bookmarkListVBox;
mapByValue(bookmarkList, bookmarkListVBox.getChildren(), bmk -> new Label(bmk.getName());
```

To automatically update the list (VBox's children) from observable list.

PS: other functions such as grouping are here => [ObservableListHelper](https://github.com/AqD/JXTN/blob/master/jxtn.jfx.axi/src/jxtn/jfx/axi/ObservableListHelper.java)

Answer (score 0):

You must not build new instances of your components everytime the view gets updated.

Instanciate them one time initialy, then you reuse and change their attributes.